# How to move the objects to the top inside array based on the matched key

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs

I have an array of objects with different keys I want to move the objects to the top based on the key I want.

Given array based on the status: **"Active"** I want all the matched objects to be moved top

```
[
   {name: "abc", age: "20", status: "Active"}, 
   {name: "xyz", age: "21", status: "Inactive"}, 
   {name: "pqr", age: "22", status: "Active"}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {name: "abc", age: "20", status: "Active"}, 
   {name: "pqr", age: "22", status: "Active"}, 
   {name: "xyz", age: "21", status: "Inactive"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let list = [{
  name: "abc",
  age: "20",
  status: "Active"
}, {
  name: "xyz",
  age: "21",
  status: "Inactive"
}, {
  name: "pqr",
  age: "22",
  status: "Active"
}]
list.sort((a, b) => (a.status !== "Active") ? 1 : -1)
console.log(list)
```

Produces the following output

```
[
  { name: 'pqr', age: '22', status: 'Active' },
  { name: 'abc', age: '20', status: 'Active' },
  { name: 'xyz', age: '21', status: 'Inactive' }
]
```

Comment: To add more to the answer, you can use the `sort` function to define the order in which they appear. The return value defines which element will occur first in the sorted array. I would recommend reading the docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Comment: There is no need to assign the sorted result to the `list` because `The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place`...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have method `Array.sort` where you can pass function that return `1, -1 or 0` which corresponds to how to move element of an array

```js
const arr = [{
  name: "abc",
  age: "20",
  status: "Active"
}, {
  name: "xyz",
  age: "21",
  status: "Inactive"
}, {
  name: "pqr",
  age: "22",
  status: "Active"
}]
console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => (a.status === b.status) ? 0 : a.status === "Active" ? -1 : 1))
```

Comment: Better to `Tidy` the result. That improves the readablility...

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code like this.

```js
function handleData(arr, status) {
   if(!arr || arr.length == 0) return
   for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    let item = arr[i];
    if(item.status == status) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      arr.unshift(item)
    }
   }
}
let arr = [{name: "abc", age: "20", status: "Active"}, {name: "xyz", age: "21", status: "Inactive"}, {name: "pqr", age: "22", status: "Active"}]

handleData(arr, 'Active')
```